# How to play video hosted on another server, in ionicApp

Tags: angularjs, html, iframe, ionic-framework

I am trying to stream videos form a remote server whose URL is provided in the JSON array. I manage to bring the video in the frame using `ngSanitize` and it works fine on my browser. My problem appears when I build for Android: it's not working and only a snippet frame is visible.

How can I play my video hosted on a remote server with my Ionic framework based app?

Here what i am doing.

**Controller:**

```
.controller("myCtrl",["$scope","$sce","$ionicLoading",function($scope,$sce,$ionicLoading){
    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
    $ionicLoading.show({
        content     : 'Loading...',
        animation   : 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth    : 200,
        showDelay   : 0,
        duration    :10000
    });

    $scope.videos=[
                    {
                      "title":"video1",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    },
                    {
                      "title":"video2",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "title":"video3",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    },
                    {
                      "title":"video4",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    },
                    {
                      "title":"video5",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    },
                    {
                      "title":"video6",
                      "source"  :"http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"
                    }
                  ];


}])
```

**view:**

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="video in videos">

         <video controls style="width:100%"> 
            <source ng-src="{{trustSrc(video.source)}}" type="video/mp4"/>
         </video> 

    </div>
```

i also used iframe (did not build to apk),but here i am not finding the way to stop my video form autoplay.

```
 <div class="card" ng-repeat="video in videos">

                 <iframe src="" dynamic-url dynamic-url-src="{{video.source}}" frameborder="0" width="100%"  controls autoplay="false"></iframe>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML `video` tag instaed of `iframe` for embedding a video in Ionic:

Example:

```
<video controls="controls" preload="auto" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer"><source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" type="video/mp4"/></video>
```